# List of DatabaseVersion values from RESTORE HEADERLISTONLY?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there a published list of expected values by SQL Server version that match to the DatabaseVersion column returned by a RESTORE HEADERLISTONLY command? For example, DatabaseVersion 611 = SQL 2005 SP_ ?

Plenty of references for SQL Server build numbers to product versions (ex. SQL Server 2005 SP3 = 9.0.4035), my Google and Bing searches do not return any references to the values for DatabaseVersion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-13-difference-between-database-version-and-database-compatibility-level/) on the web. It appears that the internal version numbers do not distinguish between service packs or cumulative updates.

- SQL Server 7.0 databases have version
  number 515
- SQL Server 2000 databases    have
  version number 539
- SQL Server    2005 databases have
  version number    611/612
- SQL Server 2008 databases    have
  version number 655

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that matter is to compare it with your current version:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ResourceVersion');
```

If the Your version is equal or higher, the backup can be restored and and upgraded (with a limit, not all past versions are supported). If is lower, the backup is from a newer version and you wont be able to restore it.

Comment: I need the list of expected values because we have backups that come from multiple sources for support reasons, and being able to determine the SQL Server version from the backup file is necessary.

Comment: I think your best bet is to contact MS customer support and ask for the list.